# Typescript: Providing default value for generic argument

Tags: typescript

During porting project from js to ts found function which takes object of certain shape and populates it values and returns it. The problem is that object is optional and can be defaulted with concrete implementation. After creating types around it compiler shows error Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'F'.
'Foo' is assignable to the constraint of type 'F', but 'F' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'FooLike'. Is there any way to fix it?

```
class Foo {
    constructor(public bar: string,
        public baz: number) { }
}

interface FooLike {
    bar: string,
    baz: number
}

const setFoo = <F extends FooLike = Foo>(value: number, foo: F = new Foo()): F => {
    foo.bar = String(value);
    foo.baz = value;
    return foo;
}

const res1 = setFoo(1);
const res2 = setFoo(1, { bar: "0", baz: 0, qux: [0]});
const res3 = setFoo(1, new Foo("0", 0));
```

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PWPAdhALgE4Cuw+8hAFAA7EBGIAlsNHWIQFzQGGM4DmAGnSZRtBs1ZgAXlxzEAtnQCmhAJQpoAX1Q7UffKoBmYYMriIAMowDW5tKLaduRPkJEY2s6PKWrdqKjYePjcyvgISAC80AA8sNDKAB6GOAAmMJHWdtAxkQB8lABuYCDEynKKKoSC0EaIXAkxOMoA7hbwlGpqjbn5KB51iAB0TrnQAMquAsWl5WoA3IP18KMy4yVlykuihOHEhDhD8Et6wQTQexAAjOMQ4ZGU14tBuBdXAEx3D4hPtchSZwAIgADEDal4uCDagBHYhJLgAbRBAF0tC9zqErgBmb4RX7XWotdqPUHg6Ag7pLVBAA

Comment: Please see the answer to the linked question for more information.